# How to create a Non-repeatable and non-clickable static header in ListView

Tags: listview, header

I am trying to create a static header for my list view , but the header repeats for every item in the list. I tried to make the linearlayout for my header, but then only header is displaying and the list view doesn't show up.

And how can I make it non-clickable. I want to implement exit functionality for the image I have created, but now, entire row is clickable.

Below is the layout code. Can someone please correct me where I am going wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >  
     <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" >
             <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Patient List"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"    
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
             android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
         />  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/exit" /> 
        </LinearLayout>     
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
     >   
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="5dip"  
    > 
    <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/patient"  
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
        > 
    </LinearLayout> 
    <!-- patient id -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" /> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstName"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" 
                /> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/patientId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" 
         android:layout_below="@id/lastName"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addHeaderView and set selectable to false.

mListView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);